# Why won't GitKraken, installed on Pop Os with Snap, start?

Tags: software-installation, snap

I am trying to install GitKraken on a System 76 computer that comes with Pop_OS! installed. Here is the linux data:

```
NAME="Pop!_OS"
VERSION="19.10"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
```

uname:
`Linux 5.3.0-7625-generic x86_64`

I used snap to install it with this command:
`sudo snap install gitkraken`

Now, when I run gitkraken in the console I get this error:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
state:  update-not-available
cat: /etc/os-release: Permission denied
```

The splash page loads, but it never gets past that. When I try to install canberra-gtk-module is loaded I see this:

```
libcanberra-gtk3-module is already the newest version (0.30-7ubuntu1).
libcanberra-gtk3-module set to manually installed.
libcanberra-gtk-module is already the newest version (0.30-7ubuntu1).
libcanberra-gtk-module set to manually installed.
```

And, when I check to see if there are odd permissions on `/etc/os-release` I see this:

```
ls -lh /etc/os-release
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Jul  9 16:14 /etc/os-release -> pop-os/os-release
```

So it is a symlink instead of a file, but it seems odd that GitKraken will not run properly. Has anyone found a solution for this? I am concerned that if I move the os-release from pop-os, future upgrades will break.

Note that I have a individual license of GitKraken, if you ask for support at this level, they email you saying to pay more for support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to caio212's answer I would suggest creating a hard link instead of copying the file. This will ensure that any future changes to the original file are carried over.

```
sudo ln /etc/pop-os/os-release /etc/os-release
```

Answer (score 2):

Had this exact problem and found the solution here: https://github.com/pop-os/pop/issues/159

The post refers to another snap but worked for me with gitkraken as well.

Solution:

Remove the symlink:

```
sudo unlink /etc/os-release
```

Copy the file to the expected location:

```
sudo cp /etc/pop-os/os-release /etc/os-release
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I will check it out as soon as possible. I frustratingly changed to the deb... but that came with it's own set of issues.